# How to get the value from the response to an allowance call

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I'm still learning, so apologies if this is a very dumb question. . . I am calling a smart contract to retrieve an allowance value, but I'm not sure how to get to the integer value in the response. My code is:

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ContractAbi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
const allowance = await contract.methods.allowance(userAddress, STAKING_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
alert(allowance);
```

The alert that is displayed in the browser is 'undefined'. I think I need it to be allowance.<something? but can't figure out what?

Thank you!

Comment: There are many reasons why your alert would display "undefined". Off the top of my head: (1) check that the contract address is correct (2) check that the network you're interacting is the same as the one you intend to interact with (3) use `console.log` instead of `alert` to make sure that the problem is not a type issue.

Comment: Also, I recommend using ethers instead of web3. Related: [What is the difference between web3.js and ethers.js?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62028/what-is-the-difference-between-web3-js-and-ethers-js).

Comment: It's hard for me to test without knowing web3 versions, contract address/abi, etc., but try just changing the middle line to `await contract.methods.allowance(userAddress, STAKING_CONTRACT_ADDRESS).call();`

Comment: Thank you @natewelch_ and @PaulRazvanBerg! The answer was I hadn't included .call(), thank you for spotting that nate. This is my first question here, is there some way I can mark your comment as correct, or give it points or something? Thank you!