# How to get account balance by using this account address i got from this code?

Tags: web3js, metamask

async function onInit() {
await window.ethereum.enable();
const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
const account = accounts[0];
console.log(account)
window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
// Time to reload your interface with accounts[0]!
console.log(accounts[0])
});
}

```
onInit();
```

const getBalance=async ()=>{
const address=await onInit();
const balance=await web3.eth.getBalance(address);
console.log(balance);
}
getBalance();
This shows the error;
Error: Provided address [object Promise] is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted.

Comment: Can you format/indent the code? Surrounding it by ``` before and after the source will mark it as code.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, I would consider using ethers (https://docs.ethers.io/v5/) instead of web3 as it's less buggy and the documentation is better. It was hard to see from your formatting but my solution for getting the balance is below:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)

const ethbalance = await provider.getBalance(address)
```

hope that helps,
Henry

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between web3.js and ethers.js?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62028/what-is-the-difference-between-web3-js-and-ethers-js).